# Kotlin navigate Drawer menu programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am looking to navigate from Home Fragment to a maps fragment by a button click without needing to open the navigation drawer.

I have used

```
requireView().findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_nav_maps)
```

but this just overrides the set fragment view to the maps fragment and if I navigate back I then have 2 of the same fragment views within the drawer, is it possible to programmatically navigate the same way as if I clicked the Maps fragment in the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the navigation to the nav_map launchSingleTop true.

And it is safe to use the androidx.navigation.fragment findNavController()

Hope it might help you..